# FB.login popup is not centered and even on separate screen than the active browser window

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

When I use the `FB.login` function from the JavaScript SDK, popup shows up, but it is aligned all the way to the right and appears on the second monitor screen. This only happens if browser window is maximized, if it is not maximized popup is centered correctly.
Reproducible in IE 10, Firefox 20

Comment: This is browser-related issue.

Comment: It might be but it was reproduced on 5 different computers some of which had blank profile (no addons, fresh install of Firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up overriding the window.open and changing the left= in attribute string. FB API puts ridiculously large number in there for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Window.open overide worked for me too...

placing code snippet to help on it:

```
  window.open = function (open) {
        return function (url, name, features) {

            var w = 475;
            var h = 183;
            // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
            var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
            var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

            var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
            var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

            var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
            var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
            var override_features = 'width=475,height=183,left=' + left + ',top=' + top + ',scrollbars=1,location=1,toolbar=0';

            // set name if missing here
            //name = name || "default_window_name";
            return open.call(window, url, name, override_features);
        };
    }(window.open);
```

w = desired popup window width
h = desired popup window height

u use the `override_feature` variable to set any param you wish.